# IDIV: Checking Boundaries

Tags: assembly, x86, division

The `IDIV` documentation (found [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html)) has this weird line that says:

```
if(Temporary > 0x7FFFFFFF || Temporary < 0x80000000) Exception(DE); //f a positive result is greater than 7FFFFFFFH or a negative result is less than 80000000H
```

What exactly is the point of this error checking? It fails if we do something like 0x80000000/-1, but it doesn't seem intuitive as to why this would do anything of use.

Note in particular that this isn't at all the case with `IMUL` found [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html).

Answer (score 1):

`idiv`'s dividend input (the concatenation of `rdx:rax`) is twice as wide as the output and divisor operands.  So the result can easily fail to fit if the divisor isn't big enough.

This rarely happens in practice, though.  It's common to simply sign-extend `rax` into `rdx` with a `cltq` (AT&T mnemonic), aka `cdq` / `cqo` (Intel/NASM mnemonic), so this usually never comes up.  128b dividend inputs would only come up in extended-precision situations.  (Compilers of course prefer to use 128 by 64 -> 64 bit division for 64bit operands, to easily support cases where the divisor doesn't fit in 32 bits.  Similarly for 32 and 16bit operands.  This could come up for `int64_t / int32_t` in 32bit-mode, though.  The compiler would know that the promoted 32bit variable would be all-zero in the upper 32, and could directly do a single `idiv`.  Except if the result didn't fit into 32b...)

Intel's insn ref manual (see links in the x86 tag wiki) comments that "Overflow is indicated with the #DE (divide error) exception rather than with the CF flag."  IDK why they made that choice, instead of only erroring on division by zero or something.